# Vim autocomplete Rails model methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, vim, autocomplete

Is it possible to configure `rubycomplete.vim` that popup scope methods at the top and gather them from models files first, than from global declaration of ActiveRecord methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using tpopes awesome [rails.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-rails) in conjunction with [exuberant ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) you can simply run the command `:Rtags` and it will generate all relevant tags for your project.

Comment: That doesn't reply to the question at all ;)

Comment: Well, but it proposes an alternative solution.